# Partition a triangle into equal areas

Tags: geometry, optimization, analytic-geometry

> A piece of wooden board in the shape of an isosceles right triangle, with sides $1$,$1$, $\sqrt{2}$ is to be sawn into two pieces. Find the length and location of the shortest straight cut which divides the board into two parts of equal area.

I think the answer would be a cut joining the midpoint of the hypotenuse and the opposite vertex. But, how can I write it out formally i.e. how to prove that this indeed is the shortest possible cut?

Comment: You can't, because it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

In the above configuration, $EF$ is the cut, where $CE=\lambda CD$ and $CF=\frac{1}{\lambda}CB$.

By the cosine theorem,
$$ EF^2 = \lambda^2 CD^2 + \frac{1}{\lambda^2} CB^2 - \sqrt{2}\, CD\cdot CB $$

hence the shortest cut is achieved by the value of $\lambda\in[1,2]$ such that $\frac{\lambda^2}{2}+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$ is minimal. By the AM-GM inequality, the minimum is attained when $\frac{\lambda^2}{2}=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$, hence for:
$$ \color{red}{\lambda = \sqrt[4]{2}}. $$
For such a configuration, the minimum cut length is so $\color{red}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}}<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, with $CEF$ being an isosceles triangle. If the cut joins two points on two equal sides, its minimal length is $1$.

Comment: What about the cuts that join points on two equal sides?

Comment: @SayantanSantra: that wasn't considered in my answer before the update, but that configuration leads to a longer cut.

Comment: And how to prove that the partitions are equal?

Comment: @SayantanSantra: that is trivial by construction: the area of $CFE$ equals the area of $CBD$, that is half the area of $ABC$.

Comment: Pardon me. Maybe I'm missing something. But, even though it seems to be obvious, I'm unable to prove it. Can you please provide some explanation?

Comment: @SayantanSantra: the area of $FCE$ is $\frac{1}{2}FC\cdot CE\sin(45^\circ) = \frac{1}{2}BC\cdot CD\sin(45^\circ)$, so the area of $FCE$ is the same as the area of $CBD$.

Comment: Oh. It's silly I didn't notice. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it. :)